# Using XmlSerializer directly with BinaryWriter - is it possible?

Tags: c#, xml, file, serialization, stream

I have a method receiving a BinaryWriter, which is itself wrapped around a FileStream.

```
    public void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)  // signature defined by interface
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ThisType));
        MemoryStream stream;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, this);                
        }
        writer.Write(stream.ToArray());
    }
```

Since XmlSerializer needs a Stream, I need to create a MemoryStream just to serialize it.

I would like to know if it's possible to serialize directly to the FileStream via `writer`, thus keeping the method signature (it is part of an interface).

Comment: `BinaryWriter` has `BaseStream` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BinaryWriter` isn't a "real" stream (it doesn't subclass `Stream`). It is more an utility class around a "real" stream (and surely it isn't a `TextWriter` subclass, another option for `XmlSerializer`).

Still, from the `BinaryWriter` you can get `BaseStream`, so:

```
public void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)  // signature defined by interface
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, this);
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Now supposing I could choose whatever signature I wanted for `Serialize` method, do you think of a better alternative than passing it a `BinaryWriter`? Maybe passing a Stream? Or maybe some common base class of `BinaryWriter`and `TextWriter`? What do you think? (and thank you for the answer!)

Comment: @heltonbiker If you want to control the encoding then you should pass a `StreamWriter`/`XmlWriter`, otherwise a `BinaryWriter` is perfectly ok.

Comment: Yeah, right. I'll keep using your code, since it serializes directly to the final stream and I don't even have to put my hands in the encoded byte array itself (encapsulation). Thanks.